# How to track if date change in different quarter in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, fiscal-periods

I have one custom date field on opportunity, i want to track if it got change to other quarter.

It can be a next quarter or previous quarter or next year or last year.

how to track this in Apex trigger?

for example 
1).my current date is 2017-02-08(YYYY-MM-DD) and i am changing this date to 2017-05-01 (this date comes in different quarter), then i want to create something in apex trigger.

OR

2). my current date is 2017-02-08(YYYY-MM-DD) and i am changing this date to 2016-07-29 (this date comes in different quarter), then i want to create something in apex trigger.

Comment: Probably you can try to retrieve the month from a date field and based on that check whether the quarter has changed or not.

Comment: If the date is changed from current to any future quarter, you want to track it?

Comment: @RahulSharma yes from current to any future or past quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the year then the quarter to find out whether date is moved to future or past or no change in quarter

**Trigger**

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert,before update,after insert,after update) {

    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter)
        OpportunityTriggerHandler.doSomething(Trigger.newMap,Trigger.OldMap);
}
```

**Handler**

```
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler {

    public static doSomething(Map<Id,Opportunity> newOpps,Map<Id,Opportunity> oldOpps) {

        for(Id recId : newOpps)
        {
            Date newDate = newOpps.get(recId).Custom_Date__c;
            Integer newDateQuarter = getQuarterNumber(newDate);
            Date oldDate = oldOpps.get(recId).Custom_Date__c;
            Integer oldDateQuarter = getQuarterNumber(oldDate);

            if(newDate.year() > oldDate.year() || (newDate.year() == oldDate.year() && newDateQuarter > oldDateQuarter))
            {
                //  Do Something for Future Quarter
            } else if(newDate.year() == oldDate.year() && newDateQuarter == oldDateQuarter) {
                //  Do Something for No Quarter change
            } else {
                //  Do Something for Past Quarter
            }

        }

    }

    public static Integer getQuarterNumber(Date d) {
        if(d.month() >= 1 && d.month() <= 3)
            return 1;
        else if (d.month() >= 4 && d.month() <= 6)
            return 2;
        else if (d.month() >= 7 && d.month() <= 9)
            return 3;
        else 
            return 4;
    }
}
```